# Equation with sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So, I got this system of equations with sets (I need to find X):

$ \begin{cases} (A \cup X) \cup C = B \cap C  \\ X \setminus A = B^\complement \end{cases}$

I got, that

$ \begin{cases} A \subseteq C \subseteq B \\ B^\complement \subseteq X \subseteq A \end{cases}$

But this means that X cannot exist like that.

So, am I right with my transformation & my conclusion?

Comment: What is your universal?  What I mean is, are $A, B \subseteq $ of what?  You will need to specify it so we know what $B^{c}$ (the complement of $B$) is.

Comment: P.S.  Assuming $X$ is your universal set, I think this does work (trivially) if you let $A = B = C = X$.

Comment: @user46944 I need to find X (what set is it equal to, or whose subset & superset is it)

Comment: Ok.  But what is the universal set?  When you define $B^{c}$, you would say $\{ x \in \text{??} \mid x \not \in B \}$.  Do you just pick some random universal set?

Comment: @user46944 Basically I assume that each set in the equation is the subset of universal set U

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$C\subseteq\left(A\cup X\right)\cup C=B\cap C\subseteq C$.

This allows
the conclusion that $A\cup X\subseteq C\subseteq B$.

Then $B^{c}=X\backslash A\subseteq B$.

This can only be true if $B^c=\emptyset$.

It follows that $X\subseteq A\subseteq C\subseteq B$ and that $B$ is the universe you are working in.

There is nothing more 'to gain'.

Answer (score 1):

$ \begin{cases} 
(A \cup X) \cup C = B \cap C \\ 
X \setminus A = B^\complement 
\end{cases}$

Substitution $L\cup M\leftarrow L\oplus M\oplus(L\cap M)$ gives

$ \begin{cases} 
(A\oplus X\oplus(A\cap X)) \oplus C\oplus (A\oplus X\oplus(A\cap X))\cap C = B \cap C \\
X\cap A^\complement = B^\complement 
\end{cases}$

$ \begin{cases} 
A\oplus X\oplus(A\cap X)\oplus C\oplus (A\cap C)\oplus X\cap C\oplus(A\cap X\cap C)= B \cap C \\
X^\complement\cup A = B
\end{cases}$

Rewritten more algebraically

$ \begin{cases} 
A+X+AX+C+AC+XC+AXC= BC \\
X^\complement+A+X^\complement A=B
\end{cases}$

Substitution of $B$

$A+X+AX+C+AC+XC+AXC= (X^\complement+A+X^\complement A)C=X^\complement C+AC+X^\complement AC$

Both sides multiplied with $X$

$XA+XX+XAX+XC+XAC+XXC+XAXC=XX^\complement C+XAC+XX^\complement AC$

and since $M+M=0$

$XA+X+AX+XC+XAC+XC+AXC=XAC\Leftrightarrow X=XAC\Leftrightarrow A\cap C\supseteq X $.